# How to link frames dynamically in excel userforms?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, frames

I am working on an excel 2013 userform which contains 3 different frames in a single userform . The first frame contains usernames, second frame contains qualification and the third contains year of passout.

Now my first frame contains radio buttons to select the user. When the user is selected I want the other two frames to automatically display the associated qualification and passout. So that when a different user is selected I get a qualification and passout of that user.

This is the Userform I am working on.

[image: Userform]

Can anyone suggest a way to proceed forward?

Answer (score -1):

Double clic on the form in the userform, this open the userform module in the VBA editor,
Here you can edit what happens when you clic on any of the entry.

For instance, you will get:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

End Sub
```

you can fill it with:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    ComboBox1.Clear
    With ComboBox1
         .AddItem "A"
         .AddItem "B"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to know how I am supposed to link the first frame with the second and third frames. I know about vba editor.

Comment: edited with an example, I am sorry I though it was clear that you can cross edit your fields. And sorry I cannot comment because I donnot have the reputation. It is not nice to downvote: I am ready to delete the answer if somebody point that is in the wrong.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you though. And i'm not using combobox just a label to display passout year and qualification.